# Creating matrix issue

Tags: c

I'm having some trouble creating a user-input matrix through a function I create. The function is as follows:

```
int create(int l, int c, int one[MAX][MAX])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < l; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < c; ++j)
        scanf("%d", &one[i][j]);
}
```

I then proceed to call my function from main :

```
int main()
{
    int mat[MAX][MAX];
    int lines, collumns;
    printf("Input # of lines, columns:\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &lines, &collumns);

    create(lines, collumns, mat[MAX][MAX]);
}
```

Oddly, if I copy the function to main and just run it as so, it works fine. But it just won't work if I try doing so through function calling, as my program crashes. What am I doing wrong guys?

Comment: This line `create(lines, collumns, mat[MAX][MAX]);` gave you at least a compiler warning, didn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
create(lines, collumns, mat[MAX][MAX]);
```

to

```
create(lines, collumns, mat);
```

and try again.

Comment: Oh my god, I can't believe this. This just goes to show what inexperience and a tired mind can lead to. Thanks mate, I appreciate it.

Comment: @MikhaelM You should accept his answer if it helped you. :) There's a little green check below the score of the post that you can click to accept it.

Comment: Thank you @Human, I'm new here and I wasn't aware of this. I accepted now it now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when passing multidimensional arrays into a function in C, the basic rule is

> You should specify the value for each of the dimension other than the first one.

So when you are passing a 2D array, define like this.

```
int create( int l, int c, int one[][MAX] ){...}
```

And when passing 3D array, define like this.

```
int create3D( int x, int y, int z, int mat[][MAX_Y][MAX_Z] ){...}
```

And when invoking the function, you only need to specify the name of the array variable. No need to specify the dimensions.

```
create( l, c, one );
create3D( x, y, z, mat );
```

You can see these errors/warnings if you compile with `-Wall` switch in `gcc`.

Good Luck!